Why is my ASP.NET Core scaffolded Create method not saving data to MySQL database?
I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project using a MySQL database for my bachelor's thesis. The application involves managing users (students, teachers, and admins) and their roles. I have the following models:
Models: User (Pouzivatel):
public class Pouzivatel
{
    public int PouzivatelId { get; set; }
    public string Meno { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int RolaId { get; set; }
    public Rola Rola { get; set; }
}

Role (Rola):
public class Rola
{
    public int RolaId { get; set; }
    public string Nazov { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pouzivatel> Pouzivatelia { get; set; }
}

DbContext:
public class AplikaciaDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Pouzivatel> Pouzivatelia { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rola> Rola { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Rola>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Pouzivatelia)
            .WithOne(p => p.Rola)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.RolaId);
    }
}

Issue:
I scaffolded a PouzivatelsController using Visual Studio to generate CRUD operations. When I try to create a user through the Create method, the user is not saved to the database, and it also doesn't show up in the list view. There are no errors in Visual Studio or the logs.
PouzivatelsController (Create method):
// GET: Pouzivatel/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["RolaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Role, "RolaId", "Nazov");
    return View();
}

// POST: Pouzivatel/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Pouzivatel pouzivatel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(pouzivatel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    ViewData["RolaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Role, "RolaId", "Nazov", pouzivatel.RolaId);
    return View(pouzivatel);
}

Create.cshtml (View):
@model Pouzivatel

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Meno" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Meno" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Meno" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RolaId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="RolaId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RolaId"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="RolaId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>

Why is the user not being saved to the database? What steps can I take to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

What happens when you step through? Is your POST method being called? Is the ModelState.IsValid true?

Are you certain you're looking in the right database?

We need to narrow down the issue, if your code worked well but just found no update in data table, you might firstly refresh the table to make sure there's not data. Then just like what Steve said you could add breakpoints in lines and see whether all codes are executed. By the way, you migth try var result = _context.Pouzivatelia.Add(pouzivatel); to see the result. By the way, you might try to comment OnModelCreating method. If all your effect doesn't work, maybe you need to provide a minimal sample for troubleshooting.
